# Visual Studio - Replace text with regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I want to replace my code with regular expression in the entire solution, but I can't find the whole message using a regular expression. I try that regular expression is 
"Convert.ToString(+MessageContext.Get([".a-zA-Z0-9]+"

Example.

I want to replace "Convert.ToString(MessageContext.Get("Dynamic Message"))" this code with "MessageContext.Get("Dynamic Message")" but i can't achieve exact this.

please help me with this.

Comment: Once you've figured out the proper regular expression, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) on how to search and replace text using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, @JoeSewell, But I already check at there and can't figure out how to use them. That's why I ask here.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of regex replace in visual studio you need to create a Group

ex:

(Convert.ToString\()+(MessageContext.get\([".a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(\){1})(\))

- (Convert.ToString\() - **Group 1**
- (MessageContext.get\([".a-zA-Z0-9]+) **Group 2**
- (\){1}) - **Group 3**
- (\)) - **Group 4**

Now you can easily replace

> (Convert.ToString\()+(MessageContext.get\([".a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(\){1})(\))

with

> $2$3

final output

> MessageContext.Get("Dynamic.Message")

I hope this will help you